# Alfresco Share client-side synchronous Form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, share, alfresco, validation

I have an Alfresco Share client-side Form in a registration scenario and I want to validate if the chosen username is taken.

Can I add a Alfresco forms validator in a synchronous way?

So far my form goes something like this:

```
this.widgets.saveForm = new Alfresco.forms.Form(this.id + "-form");
this.widgets.saveForm.addValidation(Dom.get(this.id + "-username"), this.validateUsername, me, "blur", this.msg("validation-hint.username-taken"));
```

But **this.validateUsername** needs to make an **Alfresco.util.Ajax.request** to a repo-side web service which checks availability for the chosen username. So basically, by the time the response is here, my original validateUsername method is long-finished, returning false (likely).

My progress so far is to disable the submit button (that is why I am passing "**me**" to the validation handler), and have success/failure callbacks enable it if the username is fine.

What would be a decent way to make a synchronous validator?

A side question would be if there is a better way to set the scope of the validation handler to "**this**", as opposed to passing **me** (this one works too, this is just to make sure I am not missing a better way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround solution is this:

1. Add a custom validation to the form, and pass the "var me = this" for the validator function to get the scope.

   this.widgets.saveForm.addValidation(Dom.get(this.id + "-username"), **this.validateUsername**, **me**, "blur", this.msg("validation-hint.username-taken"));
2. Add a validation handler function which will a. disable the submit button and set the "checking" CSS class to the appropriate form for the user to have feedback. Code snip:

   ```
   validateUsername: function Reg_validateUsername(el, me) {
   var val = this.fieldId.value;
   var username = trim(val);
   me.widgets.registerButton.set("disabled", true);
   Dom.addClass(me.id + "-username-img", "checking");
   Dom.removeClass(me.id + "-username-img", "hidden");
   Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({
       url: "/alfresco/service/slingshot/register/username-available?username=" + username
       , method: "GET"
       , successCallback: {
           fn: me.onUsernameAvailable
           , scope: me
       }
       , failureCallback: {
           fn: me.onUsernameTaken
           , scope: me
       }
   });
   ```
3. Write a backend webscript **username-available.get** that will return success only if the username is free (and valid, even though I have another validator for that).
4. **onUsernameAvailable** will set the submit button to enabled again and run validation again (because of other fields) and change the CSS class to "valid".
5. **onUsernameTaken** will set the CSS class to "taken".

That's how I ended up doing this.

Comment: @Zlatko  I have similar kind of problem but still its not working for me. This is link for my problem.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473813/how-to-call-synchronous-ajax-call-in-alfresco    Could you please help me for the same?

Comment: @Ranjitsinh unfortunatelly the only thing you can do is async. Make the ajax call invalidate the form on that field, and then successCallback should set it back to valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet of the create-site form. It does the same and checks if the shortname is already present and shows an error if it's taken.

```
createSiteForm.doBeforeFormSubmit =
         {
            fn: function()
            {
               var formEl = Dom.get(this.id + "-form");
               formEl.attributes.action.nodeValue = Alfresco.constants.URL_SERVICECONTEXT + "modules/create-site"; 

               this.widgets.okButton.set("disabled", true);
               this.widgets.cancelButton.set("disabled", true);

               // Site access
               var siteVisibility = "PUBLIC";
               if (this.widgets.isPublic.checked)
               {
                  if (this.widgets.isModerated.checked)
                  {
                     siteVisibility = "MODERATED";
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                  siteVisibility = "PRIVATE";
               }
               this.widgets.siteVisibility.value = siteVisibility;

               this.widgets.panel.hide();
               this.widgets.feedbackMessage = Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage(
               {
                  text: Alfresco.util.message("message.creating", this.name),
                  spanClass: "wait",
                  displayTime: 0
               });
            },
            obj: null,
            scope: this
         };

         // Submit as an ajax submit (not leave the page), in json format
         createSiteForm.setAJAXSubmit(true,
         {
            successCallback:
            {
               fn: this.onCreateSiteSuccess,
               scope: this               
            },
            failureCallback:
            {
               fn: this.onCreateSiteFailure,
               scope: this
            }
         });
```

So this is the client side JavaScript file create-site.js which does the ajax call just before the submit.

Comment: Thanks Tahir. I've already seen this code, but it does not work for me  completely. This is done before submit. What I want is right after the typing time, while the user is still filling other fields, such as email address, to have this check done in background.

Comment: Hi zladuric, I know what you want but I'm just showing how 'Alfresco' does it. Of course you can do it on typing, but then you need to add an keypress event on the field you're typing. I'm more of a jQuery fan and you can easily do a lookup with not much of work.