# How to call synchronous ajax call in alfresco?

Tags: ajax, validation, alfresco

I have one custom property say XYZ. I want to validate it on **blur** event.
I am calling one web-script using Ajax from JavaScript(Client) but its not waiting for server response and execute further code.

I am using alfresco custom validation. I have done all coding regarding custom validation and it works fine. The issue is only script is not waiting for response and continue to execute further code.

How can I make synchronous Ajax call using **Alfresco.util.Ajax**?

Following is my code and configuration which I have done.

1. I have done some configuration shar-config-custom.xml file added mandatory contraint which is calling below js.
2. validate1.js

   ---

   Alfresco.forms.validation.validate1 = function validate1(
          field, args, event, form, silent, message) {
        var temp = true;

   ```
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet ({
        url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "myscript/getdata?data=" +field.value,
     successCallback:
        {
            fn: function(response)
            {
                temp = response.json.Result;
                if (temp === "false") {
                   Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage({
                   text: "You can not go further"
                   });
                   temp = false;
                }
            },
            scope: this
     }
    });
    return temp;
   };
   ```

variable temp is always return true value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the callbacks available on the function as these are called after the operation has completed. You have one failureCallback and one successCallback.

Here is an example of a JavaScript jsonPost function using a successCallback:

```
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPost(
    {
        url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "my/webscript?nodeRef=" + nodeRef,
        successCallback: {
            fn: function (o) {

                //Make further calls

            },
            scope: this
        },
        failureMessage: "Server Error"
    });
```

If you want to block further code then you need to overwrite the relevant part of Alfresco and move the calls to the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I checked with this code but didn't work for me.

Comment: @Ranjitsinh callbacks is the correct way to go. Maybe if you provide some information on exactly what you are seeing I can help more. The specific code you are struggling with for example.

Comment: @ Mardoz  I have added my JS code for reference. Please check it.

Comment: @Ranjitsinh Ok, I see what you mean now. You can't make a synchronous request in Alfresco so you'll have to work around it, someone else's solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294604/alfresco-share-client-side-synchronous-form-validation but I see you can't get this to work either. You might be better off posting a longer explanation with all your code on the Alfresco forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate an Alfresco AJAX both sync and async as follows:

```
function myAlfrescoAjax(wsUrl, async) {
// wsUrl: string, the url of your webscript
// async: boolean, a false value simulates synchronous

    var simSync = {}; // define a local variable for simulation
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.request(
    {
    method : "GET",       
    url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + wsUrl,
        successCallback: {
            fn: function (response) {
                // insert code for succesful response
                if (!async) clearTimeout(simSync);  // resume execution  when ready (see below)
            },
            scope: this
        },
        failureMessage: "Server Error",
        execScripts: true
    });
// now immediately stop execution (if synchronous) with a timeout that takes longer than you ever expect the time the Ajax call will take
// note that this timer is killed on succes of the response function in the Ajax call
    if (!async) {
        simSync = setTimeout(function(){
        // insert code for the unexpected case the timer elapses fully
        }, 5000);
    }
    return
}
```