# Alfresco community edition in workflow start workflow using javascript

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

Alfresco community edition-5.1.x , I am creating custom workflow in workflow form check box when enable check box in background start trigger new workflow is this possible?

[image]

I tried this link but i am getting error [How to start an Alfresco Workflow through Javascript adding a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156819/how-to-start-an-alfresco-workflow-through-javascript-adding-a-resource)

Comment: Add more details on your error and approach you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Code which is mentioned in given link not plain javascript. It is alfresco javascript code.To make this work that code has to be part of webscript controller. So in your case this is how you can make it work.

- Create a webscript which will trigger workflow.
- Call that webscript on selection of checkbox. ([How to call synchronous ajax call in alfresco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473813/how-to-call-synchronous-ajax-call-in-alfresco))

Comment: but when create web script it is working separately , my scenario is custom workflow inside workflow form check box enable or disabled if enabled check box custom javascript i want trigger another workflow